# Convert a Cookie object in to string format and back

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, cookies

How can I convert a cookie/cookie collection in to its string representation? (in ASP.Net)

What I am looking for is

```
cookie-collection  => "name1=value1 expires=date1; name2=value2 path=/test"
```

and vice-versa.

Comment: How far have you got already?

Comment: I have something similar to what @Stecya has posted. I am looking for a library which will help me do this. I am surprised that the base framework does not expose this already!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
   //Convert to string
   HttpCookieCollection source = new HttpCookieCollection();
   string result = source.Cast<HttpCookie>().
                   Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, cookie) => 
                   current + string.Format("{0}={1} ", cookie.Name, cookie.Value));


   //Convert back to collection
   HttpCookieCollection dest = new HttpCookieCollection();
   foreach (var pair in result.Split(' '))
   {
        string[] cookies = pair.Split('=');
        dest.Add(new HttpCookie(cookies[0],cookies[1]));
   }
```

Comment: I have something similar to this now. but it currently does not handle parameters like expires, path, domain etc. I am looking for some library which i can use, instead of rolling my own code if i can avoid it.